# How to make the line number in algorithm shown in bold

Tags: fonts, algorithms, line-numbering, algorithmic

I have tried following which works (making the number in second line bold)

```
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State TSO.assignStartTs()
{\bf\State} TSO.assignCommitTs()
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

The problem is if I want to make the same for first linenumber, as below, it does not work, and complaints with `Missing endcsname`. This looks quite like undefined behaviour to me, and in general, is there anyway to make line number bold?

```
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
{\bf\State} TSO.assignStartTs()
{\bf\State} TSO.assignCommitTs()
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that it works in the second line is just by chance. It's better to use a specific command that boldens the next number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\newif\ifboldnumber
\newcommand{\boldnext}{\global\boldnumbertrue}

% Default definition is \footnotesize#1:
\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{%
  \footnotesize\ifboldnumber\bfseries\fi\global\boldnumberfalse#1:}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\boldnext
\State TSO.assignStartTs()
\State TSO.assignCommitTs()
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]